# How to edit labels added drag and drop in a loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, label, connected-components

I have a list of labels as shown in this image [image: The labels' Image] which been added to the form by dragging and dropping and they are named from Label1 to Label160 sequentially, when I want to put a condition to change the color of the white labels (as can be seen in the image) in a nested loop to check the label in left and top of each label and change the color accordingly (connected components algorithm) it gives me an error and says "the name .... does not exist in the current context" or when I use the Label[i] it says "System.windows.form.Label is a type but is used as a variable" anyways I am not able to work on the labels in a loop.
any way to fix that?
appreciate your help

Comment: You really dragged, dropped, positioned, named etc. 160 labels on the form? Omg. Try `Controls["Label1"]` and similar.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you find it helpful :)

Comment: @Hakar When you find a post that answers your question, you can kindly click on check mark near the answer to make it accepted. While you can only mark one answer as accepted, you can vote up as many answer as you find helpful, including the accepted one by click on up arrow near the answer. You can also vote for good questions by click on up arrow near the question. This makes question and answers more useful for future readers :)

Comment: Thank you dear @RezaAghaei, your answer really helped me and it worked, sorry for the late vote up, I was away :)

Comment: You are welcome, Happy to hear that it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Controls` collection to gain access to controls of a container.

For example if you put your labels on form, you can use (don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`):

```
foreach(var label in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    //Get or Set properties of label
    //label.BackColor == Color.White;
}
```

or if you are sure all labels named with Label1 to Label160, the you can use:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=160; i++)
{
    var label = this.Controls[string.Format("Label{0}", i)];
    //Get or Set properties of label
    //label.BackColor == Color.White;
}
```

Comment: For first solution don't forget to add using `System.Linq;`

Comment: The other thing that you should know is you can do the same thing using a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` and adding those labels using code, this way you don't need to add those labels in designer and arrange them and change their names manually.

Comment: Thank you dear @Reza, your second answer worked for me. plus, i'm new in c# so I didn't know about this Controls["Label1"] stuff that's why i did with drag and drop, but it didn't took me time, i dragged 2 labels and copied from them which gave the names sequentially and was kinda easy :)
thank you again for the answer bro :)